# Restoring a working GUI ubuntu desktop 22.04 after driver manipulation

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, xorg, 22.04

I have a asus laptop running ubuntu 22.04, I upgraded from 20.04 a month ago

I noticed since the upgrade, sometimes when exiting the sleeping/suspend mode (not using for 10/15mn) I get stuck on a black screen and I can't do nothing until a hard shutdown (5sec press on power button).

I tried different things I found on internet and none of them worked. I made changes myself which are

- in nvidia settings changing from performance mode to power save mode (I have a GT635M)
- changed the nvidia driver to the community driver

Then the problem happend again, I shutdown my computer and when rebooting it, I'm stuck on a black screen after cleaning orphans nodes

I started in recovery mode to launch root console, the hard drive works well, I assume there is something with the X server

All of the solutions I found on internet imply to use `apt install ...`, but even activating the network manager I can't get a internet connection and can't try these solutions

Hence I'm stuck with more or less 2 problems

Having the GUI to works

Having a wifi connection in the recovery console

Few commands I ran :

```
$ ununtu-drivers devices
Modalias...
Vendor nvidia
Model GF108M [Geforce GT 635M]
Manual_install true
Driver nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
Driver xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260[8086:08b1] (rev 73)
Subsystem: intel corporation dual band wireless-ac 7260[8086:4470]
$ lshw -class network
*-network UNCLAIMED
    My ethernet controller
*-network UNCLAIMED
   Description network controller
   Product wireless 7260
   Manufacturer intel corp
   Hardware id 0
   Bus infos pci@0000:03:00.0
   Version 73
   Bits 64
   Clock 33mhz
   Functionalities pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   Config latency=0
   Ressources memory:f7800000-f7801fff

$ ls /sys/class/net
lo
$ nmcli d
Device type     state       connection
Lo     loopback not-handled --
```

I also tried `dconf reset -f /` but can't launch D-bus without $DISPLAY X11

Thanks for any help, I appreciate it

Comment: I edited the post, they are both ubuntu desktop, I'm not sure if it was 20.02 or 20.04 and I upgraded to 22.04
I didn't know the differences thank you for your explanations

Comment: Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format; and there was no release in 2020-February (20.02; 2000 is added to the *year*) so I'd check your details.  Ubuntu products are developed on a two year cycle; three non-LTS releases before the final LTS which is always the first release of the *even* year.... ie. 22.10 or the recent 2022-October release being the first release on the cycle that will conclude with 24.04. Ubuntu 22.04 = 2022.April release, but 22 was released in 2022.July but no month used as different system (22 & 22.04 are different products)